# form serialize leaves text inputs empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using a ajax/php file uploader. I have added additional form fields to it. The hidden form fields which have values declared get passed no problem, but any text field with user inputted values are empty. I checked with httpfox and all text input values are blank on form submission there. Perhaps its because the ajax file uploader automatically submits the form after file upload somehow preventing values entered after browser load to be passed? not really sure here.

here is my form:

```
   <link href="css/uploadfilemulti.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.fileuploadmulti.min.js"></script> 

<form id="uploadform" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset>  
    <legend>Some Info</legend>
    <ol><li>
    <label for="title">NAME:</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" />
    </li><li>
    <label for="ink">SALES REP:</label>
    <input id="ink" name="ink" type="text" value="" /><p class="small">Your sales rep.</p></li><li>
    <label for="paper">TELEPHONE NUMBER:</label>
    <input id="paper" name="paper" type="text" value="" /><p class="small">How can we reach you?</p></li>
    <li><label for="description">DESCRIPTION:</label>
    <textarea id="description" name="description" value="" /></textarea>
    </li><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $mn; ?>" name="member_name" id="member_name" /><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ship_city']; ?>" name="ship_city" id="ship_city" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ship_state']; ?>" name="ship_state" id="ship_state" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" name="ship_company" id="ship_company" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['member_id']; ?>" name="member_id" id="member_id" /></ol></fieldset></form>
```

here is the ajax handler:

```
<div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div>

<div id="status"></div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{

var theForm = $('#uploadform').serialize();
//$.post('url', formData);
var settings = {
    url: "pruploadonly_do.php",
    method: "POST",
    allowedTypes: "jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip,psd,ai,eps,jpeg,cdr,tif,JPG",
    fileName: "myfile",
    multiple: true,
    formData: theForm,
    onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
    {
        $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");

    },
    afterUploadAll:function()
    {
        alert("all images uploaded!!");
    },
    onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
    {       
        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
    }
}
$("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for js/jquery.fileuploadmulti.min.js ? Are you really still using the `<font>` tag and styling with HTML?

Comment: @PHPglue http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery <-- link to fileuploadmulti.min.js docs. And the <font> tag was part of that file. I didn't write that.

Comment: @PHPglue sorry. wrong link.. its here: http://hayageek.com/jquery-multiple-file-upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do it with this plugin.  This plugin is built to setup itself up as soon as the DOM is loaded.  that's what creates the upload button.  So by the time you add form data, that doesn't get added into the configuration that gets sent via AJAX.

You'll need to use different code, like the first link you gave above: http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery

Comment: I figure this was the problem. However, anytime I add any click function to the javascript, it wont display the upload button. I think its something in the js file. here it is: https://rawgithub.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/master/js/jquery.uploadfile.min.js

Comment: here is one not minimized.. https://rawgit.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file/master/js/jquery.uploadfile.js

Comment: yeah i found that.  checking it out now.

Comment: Thanks, I just found where the author supplies this addition to the plugin in the comments: http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/jquery-multiple-file-upload/extraForm/index.php  browse for a file and then it shows a form below it..I cant use the one I accidentally pasted the link to in my first comment as it doesn't seem to support multi file uploads, which is a must for this application.

Comment: I just got it working with the aditional plugin from the author. I will accept your answer as the other plugin being not usable for my needs. Thanks again!

Comment: well thanks!  i'll update the answer to incude what you found.

Comment: what's the link for the plugin?

Comment: http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/jquery-multiple-file-upload/extraForm/index.php I just viewed source and got the plugin files.